# How secure is the Android apk certificate

Tags: android, security, certificate, apk, signature

I have a piece of code in my application that retrieves the application certificate at runtime and uses it as a key to encrypt some confidential information.

Is it possible for some attacker to get that certificate `byte[]` by decompiling my code or is that certificate only visible to my application?

Here is how I get the certificate:

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    String packageName = this.getPackageName();
    int field = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;
    PackageInfo packageInfo;

    packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, field);

    Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;

    // and here we have the DER encoded X.509 certificate
    byte[] certificate = signatures[0].toByteArray()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PackageInfo signature is public key,

It is not private key. And this key is accessible to any app installed on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

The application certificate is public; the private key used to sign the app never leaves your possession (unless you give it away).  The private key cannot be reconstructed from the public key.  The only way they would be able to decrypt your confidential info is via some sort of brute force attempt, against which there is ultimately no defense.  Fortunately for you, the expense of running such a brute force attempt is so large that nobody in their right mind would attempt it unless they thought there were nuclear secrets etc. inside.